# Newlines in iOS 7 UITextView breaking Text Kit exclusion zone wrapping

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, textkit

I'm working with Text Kit in iOS 7 and I'm finding a lot of oddities around `NSTextContainer` exclusion zones.

I've got two views: a `UITextView` and a simple draggable `UIView`; as the `UIView` moves, I create a bezier path from the `UIView`'s frame (adjusted to within the `UITextView`'s coordinate space) and I update the `UITextView`'s `NSTextContainer`'s `exclusionPaths` array - pretty straightforward.

In the first screenshot, you can see that Text Kit nicely wraps text around a rectangular exclusion zone:

[image: Exclusion zone with no newlines in text]

However, when the user introduces newlines into the `UITextView`, TextKit seems to think that the exclusion zone is much bigger vertically - by what appears to be exactly as high as the whitespace created by the newline. The bezier path is exactly the same, so this seems to be a Text Kit issue (unless I'm doing something wrong).

[image: Exclusion zone with newlines in text]

Code:

**ViewController.h:**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *dragView;

@end
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [self.dragView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

    [self updateExclusionZone];
}

-(void)move:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
{
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[pan view]];

    if ([pan state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"pan began");
    }

    self.dragView.center = [pan locationInView:self.view];
    [self updateExclusionZone];

    if ([pan state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"pan ended");
    }
}

-(void)updateExclusionZone
{
    CGRect dragViewFrame = self.dragView.frame;
    CGRect exclusionRect = [self.view convertRect:dragViewFrame toView:self.textView];

    UIBezierPath *exclusion = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:exclusionRect];

    self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[exclusion];
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today.

This bug seem to appear, if you set `editable` and `selectable` at the same time. If only one or no is selected, it renders as expected. Both are selected by default.

[image]
[image]

If you need both options, just set them in code.

```
_textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = exclusionPaths;
_textView.attributedText = attrString;
_textView.editable = YES;
_textView.selectable = YES;
```