# Incorrect exclusionPaths with new lines in a UITextView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm have a problem with exclusionPaths when a textView has new line characters:

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
  UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 333, 360, 480)];
  view.frame = CGRectMake(50, 0, 50, 50);
  view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(view.frame));
  [textView addSubview:view];

  CGRect relativeRect = [textView convertRect:view.bounds fromView:view];

  UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:relativeRect];
  textView.text = @"asddsaadasddsasdasdjsdhfjkdhkjdhfgjkldhsgfjlk\n\nhfdsgjklhdfsljkghdklfjgshdgjklfshdfgjklhfglkjdshjklgfdshjklgdfshkljfdsghfjkldghlkjfdghskljgdfhslkjgdfshjklgfdshjkgfdshlkjgdfhskljdgfhsjklgdhsjklfgdshjkglfdshjklgfdshlkjfgdhjklgdfshjdfkslghkjfdlsghjkldsfghjkhdfsgkjlhjgkldfshgdflksjhfdksgjhdfkjlgshfkljdshgjkdfhskjglhdfsjkghdfkjglhdsfkjghkljdfhgkjlhdsfkjlghjkldsfghjklhgsfdjklhgsdfkjlghdsfklgfdhsklg";
  textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[bezierPath];
  [self.view addSubview:textView];

}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

The problem being that the new line characters make the exclusionPaths bigger than they should be. The issue is also described here: [Newlines in iOS 7 UITextView breaking Text Kit exclusion zone wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963648/newlines-in-ios-7-uitextview-breaking-text-kit-exclusion-zone-wrapping), but it shows how to fix this iOS 7 bug if using Interface Builder to create the UITextView. How would I fix this programatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the winning property to disable is "scrollEnabled":

```
textView.editable = NO
textView.scrollEnabled = NO
```

The above code fixes my issues with exclusionPaths

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in subclass of TextView if you need editable textView

```
 - (void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];

self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
```