# NSTextContainer exclusionPaths move with text

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, nstextcontainer

I am trying to implement `exclusionPaths` for my custom views inside `UITextView`, and move them with text during text editing similar like in Pages app.
I am trying to add a custom attribute for the `attributedText`, where custom view should be and I am updating `exclusionPaths` using `boundingRectForGlyphRange` for custom attribute after `textViewDidChange`.
I have a problem when the user enters a new line, I am using `exclusionPaths` so when the user hits the new line character before the image, my custom attribute is below `exclusionPath` and origin `y` of `boundingRectForGlyphRange` is at the wrong place.

Any ideas?

[image: Correct position]

[image: Wrong position]

EDIT: The problem was an Apple bug during loading `UITextView` from storyboard/xib, [Newlines in iOS 7 UITextView breaking Text Kit exclusion zone wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963648/newlines-in-ios-7-uitextview-breaking-text-kit-exclusion-zone-wrapping) this helped me, and i am just adjusting exclusionPaths in shouldChangeTextInRange when the replacement text is "\n".

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this in subclass of TextView

```
 - (void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];

self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
```

Helps for me

Comment: Then please provide the correct answer and accept it