# Make multiline UILabel wrap a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am using storyboard to design my `UIView`. But I've stuck at the task: I have a multiline `UILabel`, `UIView` and `UIButton`. I want to make `UILabel` to wrap my button - the fist line of the text has a trailing constraint to `UIButton` another one to it's super view. And if my UILabel has no text I got a view at the bottom of label and I need to make this view trailing constraint to `UIButton` but if I got a free space - to it's superview. 
Screenshot example:

[image]

I want to jump second line word after 'pyat' . Sorry for my poor english, hope that picture could help to explain my question.
Is it possible to make it directly in IB?

Comment: I'd suggest to use a `UITextView` instead of a `UILabel` (with some quick modification, it would look like and act like a `UILabel`) and use `yourTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths`, but that would be with code and not IB.

Comment: Sorry , It is not possible with interfacebuilder

Comment: @Jecky Can you advice me how to do this? Obj-c language

Comment: As above comment, You can easily do with textview and its method but with label you can only find width of label. I will try it ,if possible I will post my code

Comment: @Jecky @Larme the problem using `UITextView` is that sometimes I have zero text in label and I need to wrap this button with `UIView` below my label

Comment: But as per your screenshot your button is fixed by constraint I think, So If you have text of textview as zero then it is remain same as it were

Comment: @Jecky I mean that if my text is zero - the trailing constraint of the next view should be to UIButton not to super view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124994/discussion-between-jecky-and-artem-z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps instead of using `UILabel` you can try `UITextView` by using its `textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths` property to define a button container area to exclude.

Have a look at the [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632474/uitextview-textcontainer-exclusion-path-fails-if-full-width-and-positioned-at-to) with a [reported issue for selected and editable case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963648/newlines-in-ios-7-uitextview-breaking-text-kit-exclusion-zone-wrapping).

As I remember you must limit the app deployment target minimum to 7 or later if using this property.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not supported out of the box and will take a lot of work because it will require subclassing UILabel and overriding drawRect.

An easy solution is to set attributed text on the label and use that to format the specific word to look like a button. UILabel attributed text supports  hyperlink like behavior.